#  If i install a package say "mypack.apk" ,then will "/data/data/com.Android.mypack" will get created always 

Tags: android, file, file-io

```
        File fileDir = getFilesDir();
     Log.v("TEST","FILEDIR--->"+ fileDir.toString());  //prints   FILEDIR--->/data/data/com.Android.mypack/files


    String strNewFileName = "test1.txt";
    String strFileContents = "TEST PRG, NOTHN  MUCH";


    File newFile = new File(fileDir, strNewFileName);
    try{
    boolean filestat = newFile.createNewFile();
    Log.v("TEST"," CREATE FILE =>"+ filestat);  //Prints true indicating a successful creation

    FileOutputStream fo =
        new FileOutputStream(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
        fo.write(strFileContents.getBytes());
        fo.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) 
    {}
```

After running the program with a android tablet. I mounted the tablet and used the file explorer to find the file in the internal storage. But i'm not able to locate a path like "/data/data/com.Android.mypack/files ".  How to confirm that a new file is created ? or how to check it from the UI using a file manager.

OR

If i install a package say "mypack.apk" ,then will "/data/data/com.Android.mypack" will get created ? I'm not able to view it . I tired using andexplorer and its empty

Comment: do you have terminal emulator on your phone? try browsing using the commmand prompt of it.

Comment: As i said a tablet , I don't have terminal emulator. I mounted the tablet and i did a search for "test1.txt, But i couldnt find it. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse then you can check if the file is present or not by following way.

On the top right corner of your eclipse there is option to select DDMS(If you dont see it click on "Open Perspective" icon).

DDMS -> File Explorer -> data -> data -> com.Android.mypack -> files -> (your file if it is created)

It will show you the files of your tab also.just select your tab on left side.

Comment: Yes,I'm using Eclipse. But in DDMS view i see my Device under the Devices Tab. Next to it i see Threads,Heap,File Explorer. But the File Explorer is blank. (I'm not using emulator,directly running the application on device)

Comment: No problem if you are not using emulator. It is showing you blank because you have not selected your tab device. Just click on your Device under Device tab then your File Explorer will not remain blank!! :)

Comment: selected  my Device from the Devices tab and it still shows blank. Have mounted my device also. Closed and reopened Eclipse. ( Logcat runs fine as its getting updated. Not file Explorer)

Comment: If it is recognizing the device then it should show you. Try to do the same by command prompt. Navigate to platform-tools in command prompt and execute `adb shell`. in that # prompt navigate to your folder by cd data/data/com.Android.mypack and say `ls`

Comment: And if still you are not getting anything then install this apk on your tab and explore [http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andexplorer/](http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andexplorer/)

Comment: I installed this APK. But  /data is empty :(                             But in the log i get ,FILEDIR--->/data/data/com.Android.mypack/files

Comment: what do you mean when you say you mount the device?

Comment: In the notifications , i Click on Mount . so that i am able to see the files from my PC.If i mount thats when i will be able to see the files of my device on PC.